# How to apply filename patterns on PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver?

Tags: java, spring

I'm loading resources from the file system as follows using wildcards:

```
Resource[] resources = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver()
    .getResources("/my/path/*.zip");
```

Question: how can I load only `.zip` files that NOT have an underscore `_` in the filename? 
Is that possible using the wildcard patterns at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/support/PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.html) will use the [AntPathMatcher](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/AntPathMatcher.html) by default,
which (luckily) can do RegExp based wildcards, so you can use it like this:

```
Resource[] resources = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver()
     .getResources("/my/path/{filename:[^_]*.zip}");
```

`[^_]` - is a negated character range, which will match any character except for `_`, so `[^_]*.zip` will, in turn, match any filenames that end with .zip and do not have `_` in their name.